# How to echo all messages with "websockets/ws"

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm using this websocket : https://github.com/websockets/ws and I want to send a message from one client to another. To begin with that, I wanted to echo the messages sent to the server, but the messages are just received by the client which has sent them. I know, that this works pretty easy with socket.io, but I have to use websockets/ws .
This is my server code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
    ws.send(message); //This echoes the message
  });

  ws.send('Connection Opened');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over all the clients connected to the socket server. Replace your `ws.send(message);` with

```
wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
  client.send(message);
});
```

Comment: Okay, I've already found a similar solution, which pushes all new clients into a list, but this one is way more intuitive thanks :)